# How to create a log file in pg_log directory for each execution of my function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a log file as " /opt/postgres/9.2/data/pg_log/postgresql-2018-08-19.csv".  Due to "log_rotation_age=1d", one log file will be created for me in this pg_log directory on everyday.

While I am debugging a particular user defined function which contains the lot of  raise notice  messages , I would like to create a new log file instead of appending the logs to existing one. How to achieve this?

Like this each and every execution of my function, I wold like to get a new log file. How to do this.

Comment: er... probably your best bet is to make the function write its "notices" to a separate file. Also, pretty sure RAISE NOTICE output isn't logged. Maybe I've just not set the right setting but I've never seen RAISE NOTICE content in log files even with full statement logging enabled.

Comment: @eurotrash `log_min_messages = notice`, but you can't direct them to a separate file.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks, good to know. Re: file, I meant instead of RAISE NOTICE, change the function to write them to another file via COPY TO

Comment: Yes, I got you. That second part was addressed at the OP.

Comment: I have explored and find the command as "select pg_rotate_logfile();" to recreated the log file whenever I need. Could you give an example " I meant instead of RAISE NOTICE, change the function to write them to another file via COPY TO "